# Unable to query in a rails has_many :through relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

I am trying to get my relationships worked out but I am having trouble using the associations.

So I have three models `User`, `Shop` and `Access`. A user should have many shops and a shop should have many users.

The models are :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accesses
  has_many :stores, through: :accesses
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accesses
  has_many :users, through: :accesses
end

class Access < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :store
end
```

The corresponding schema is

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140108102103) do

  create_table "accesses", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "store_id"
    t.string   "permission"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "stores", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "tin"
    t.text     "address"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "store_name"
    t.float    "credit"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Now, when I query `User.first.stores`

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :accesss in model User
```

Does anyone have any idea why I am getting this error?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you have `class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accesses
  has_many :stores, through: :accesses
end` and not `class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accesss
  has_many :stores, through: :accesses
end`?

Comment: Yes I am completely sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm kind of shooting in the dark here, but try:

```
# config/initializers/inflections.rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'access', 'accesses'
end
```

Comment: This actually worked! Could you please tell what was wrong and what this code is doing?

Comment: The `Inflector` transforms words from singular to plural, class names to table names, modularized class names to ones without, and class names to foreign keys. The default inflections for pluralization, singularization, and uncountable words are kept in `inflections.rb`. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html (See help for `ActiveSupport::Inflector::Inflections` too)

Answer (score 0):

I've copied all your code on a new project.

```
 => #<User id: 1, email: "test@test.com", encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2014-01-08 16:52:01", updated_at: "2014-01-08 16:52:01"> 
 2.0.0-p353 :004 > User.first
 User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 1, email: "test@test.com", encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2014-01-08 16:52:01", updated_at: "2014-01-08 16:52:01"> 
 2.0.0-p353 :005 > User.first.stores
 User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 Store Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "stores".* FROM "stores" INNER JOIN "accesses" ON "stores"."id" = "accesses"."store_id" WHERE "accesses"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

Everything works fine. Rails 4.0.1, ruby 2.0.0-p353.
Seems problem is in some other code. Or in a typo, but I've copied code directly from here into a new model.

Also just a blind shot: do you store each model in a separate file?